# Run logstash as a service and view stdout

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have used the RPM installation of logstash. As such, logstash is running as a linux service. I would like to debug a pipeline and need to view the contents of

```
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But, since logstash is started as a service - where/how do you view stdout? Is there a way to pipe the contents of rubydebug into the log file at `/var/log/logstash/logstash.log`?

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the init script that I have, it includes this:

```
 > "${LS_LOG_DIR}/$name.stdout"
```

And I get /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout

Comment: what do you mean by init script? can you elaborate?

Comment: Init scripts are scripts that live in /etc/init.d and are used by some flavors of linux to control daemon processes (i.e. services)

Answer (score 5):

Most Linux distros use `systemd` now (instead of `sysvinit`) to run services so the 2016 solution no longer works on most Linux systems.

If your Linux distro has `systemd`, to view stdout from `logstash` use the command: `journalctl -f -u logstash`. No need to edit any file/script and works with the `stdout` output in `logstash`.